# Add parameters to method roslyn beginning

Tags: c#, roslyn

Could you help me do it this? I`m Roslyn beginner :D

-> Send to number3 in this tree (number five) "number3 = 5"

-> Send to method in tree number1 (number 2) and number2 (number 2) "Method(2,2)"

-> Return value from this method "int returnValue = Method(2,2)"

-> Return value from number3 "int someNumber = number3"

[image]

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            project1();
        }

        public static void project1()
        {
            var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(@"
            class OurService
            {
                int number3;
                int Method(int number1, int number2)
                {
                    return number1 +  number2 + number3;
                }
            }");


            var diagnostics = tree.GetDiagnostics().Where(n => n.Severity == Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.DiagnosticSeverity.Error).FirstOrDefault();

            var root = (CompilationUnitSyntax)tree.GetRoot();

            var methodDeclareted = root.DescendantNodes().OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>().FirstOrDefault();
            var parameters = methodDeclareted.ParameterList;

        }
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: @AntP I`m sorry I print this from another place and I forgotten add question. Now it`s ok.

Comment: It is still not really clear what you're trying to achieve (at least to me). Could you please try to explain what you're trying to do in a bit more detail?

Comment: @bassfader is it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix this issue by myself. I would like to add only this "Roslyn is great tool. You can remove IronPython and Python". I hope in future I will get some points for this :P because now I get for my question -1 :P hehe

[image]

```
public static void TestCodeAnalizer()
        {

            //var scriptOptions = ScriptOptions.Default.WithReferences("Microsoft.CSharp")
            var text = @"using System.Linq; 

            public class Calculator
            {

            public int number3 = 0;

            public static object AddTwoNumbers(int number1, int number2)
            {
                return (number1 + number2);
            }

            public static int AddThreeNumbers(int number1, int number2)
            {
                Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
                return calculator.AddThreeNumbersNonStatic(number1,number2,5);
            }

            public int AddThreeNumbersNonStatic(int number1, int number2, int number3)
            {
                this.number3 = number3;

                return (number1 + number2 + this.number3);
            }

            }";

            var tree = SyntaxFactory.ParseSyntaxTree(text);
            var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(
                "calc.dll",
                options: new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary),
                syntaxTrees: new[] { tree },
                references: new[] { MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location), MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(ExpandoObject).Assembly.Location) });

            Assembly compiledAssembly;
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var compileResult = compilation.Emit(stream);
                compiledAssembly = Assembly.Load(stream.GetBuffer());
            }

            Type calculator = compiledAssembly.GetType("Calculator");

            //my send parameters :D
            object[] parametersArray = new object[] { 2, 2 };

            //first answer
            MethodInfo evaluate_AddTwoNumbers = calculator.GetMethod("AddTwoNumbers");
            string answer_AddTwoNumbers = evaluate_AddTwoNumbers.Invoke(null, parametersArray).ToString();

            //second answer
            MethodInfo evaluate_AddThreeNumbers = calculator.GetMethod("AddThreeNumbers");
            string answer_AddThreeNumbers = evaluate_AddThreeNumbers.Invoke(null, parametersArray).ToString();


        }
```